# How can I jump between opening and closing tags in Visual Studio?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, tags, vscode-extensions, key-bindings

When I code I want to jump from a closing tag of `</div>` or any sort of tag from the bottom to the corresponding opening tag.

I have other extension which are showing me opening and closing tags but basically I am looking for a shortcut key to achieve both. From bottom to top and vice versa.

I'm wasting my time to scroll or minimize a div.

Comment: Have you tried looking for the keybinds in your preferences? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that work fine for me. 
First is press CTRL+SHIFT+P and type in `Emmet: Go to matching pair`, this just marks the corresponding bracket.
 When pressing CTRL+SHIFT+^ I jump directly to the corresponding bracket (^ is the button above TAB, just in case it is unclear). 
If it does not work for You press CTRL K then CTRL S and type in `Go to bracket` and set a keybinding that You like. For curly brackets use `Go to bracket` and for HTML code blocks use the option `Emmet: Go to matching pair` inside the settings and set a keybind. 
I hope this helps.